# how to output values of checkboxes

Tags: javascript

i am trying to output form values with inner.html
I got 2 problems with my checkboxes: 
1. if i check more then 1 checkbox, only one is outputted
2. if no checkbox is checked, the input from other fields are also not outputted
How can i fix this problem?

```
<script>function changeText(){
var userInputname = document.getElementById('name').value;
var userInputcolor = document.querySelector('.color:checked').value;

document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = userInputname;
document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = userInputcolor;
return false;
}
</script>

<form method="get" onsubmit="return changeText()">        
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />        
<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="color" class="color" value="green">Green<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="color" class="color" value="yellow">Yellow<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="color" class="color" value="red">Red<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="color" class="color" value="blue">Blue<br />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Output" />
<br /><br />
<b id='output1'></b><br />
<b id='output2'></b><br />
```

Comment: And why do all the checkboxes have the same name?

Comment: @adeneo It is fine to have multiple elements with the same `name`, but not with the same `id`.

Comment: @adeneo - Checkboxes with the same name don't necessarily present a problem...

Comment: i should give them different names each?

Comment: I know it's not invalid, I'm just asking why they all have the same name?

Comment: @chris97ong - mostly because most serverside languages won't receive multiple values when more than one checkbox is checked, so it's not something you see very often, unless it's for radio buttons or the name is something like `name[]`, that many serverside languages understands as an array.

Comment: You probably want `querySelectorAll` not `querySelector`.

Comment: well the problem is, i don't know how to handle with these checkboxes, so i tried something like this; but what i want is when check the checkbox (one or more) they must be outputted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector` only gets one single element, the first one encountered, you'd use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all matching elements, and you can convert that to an array and use map to return a concantenated string of the values, like this :

```
<script>function changeText(){
var userInputname = document.getElementById('name').value;
var userInputcolor = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".color:checked")).map(function(el) {
        return el.value;
    }).join(', ')

document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = userInputname;
document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = userInputcolor;
return false;
}
</script>

<form method="get" onsubmit="return changeText()">        
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />        
<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="color" class="color" value="green">Green<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="color" class="color" value="yellow">Yellow<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="color" class="color" value="red">Red<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="color" class="color" value="blue">Blue<br />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Output" />
<br /><br />
<b id='output1'></b><br />
<b id='output2'></b><br />
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4VGAa/)

Comment: Awesome! That's just what i wanted to make possible. Thanks very much for support